# How to categorise issues in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

I am using SonarQube 5.4, i want to club issues under same issue type. For example, if an issues comes for Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true" ,   then all classes having this kind of issue may club together.

I have also attached screenshot of my sonarqube where different issues are mentioned.

[sonarqube screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFyjs.png)

Thanks,
Rahul Chauhan

Comment: In the left side bar, there is the "rules" facet. It allows to filter on only one rule. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: You should consider upgrading to SonarQube 6.7, which is the latest LTS !